# Convert a two column matrix into a comma separated vector

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have a matrix:

```
> m <- matrix(c(1:6), ncol = 2)
> m
     [,1] [,2] 
[1,]    1    4 
[2,]    2    5 
[3,]    3    6
```

And I would like to obtain:

```
> "1 4", "2 5", "3 6"
```

Comment: do you really want `1 4` a character vector?

Comment: It is not clear what answer you want.  What you wrote does not look like an R data structure.  In some way you already have what you want in that `m[1,]` will produce `1 4` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can transpose, and concatenate to get a `vector`

```
c(t(m))
#[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

If we really need a character vector, loop through the rows and `paste`

```
apply(m, 1, paste, collapse=" ")
#[1] "1 4" "2 5" "3 6"
```

Or for printing

```
cat(do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m)), sep=", ")
#1 4, 2 5, 3 6
```

Comment: The `do.call(paste...` option seems to be a lot faster for big datasets compared to `apply(m, 1, paste...`

Comment: @thelatemail  I was a bit hesitant as it had the overhead of data.frame, but thanks for your note.